# Connecting a printer directly to the Google Cloud Print server

Tags: networking, printer, network-printer, cloud

I want to connect my printer directly with google cloud print server, so I won't need to have a pc 24/7 open to print orders, the printer should directly communicate with google cloud server. My thermal printer is not google cloud print ready though and has only one usb port. How should i do that?

Up to part 3 on the photo it is done, problem are steps 3-4. I am looking for a solution to connect the thermal printer on the cloud without the need of PC.
[image]

Comment: You don't, because you can't physically connect to a cloud.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I suppose you can if the printer is cloud print ready

Comment: "My thermal printer is not google cloud print ready" I think we've already settled that part.

Comment: yes we are just discussing

Comment: So, is there another way to connect it to the cloud without using a pc?

Comment: There's nothing to discuss. Your requirements are impossible. You need *some* sort of computer, even if a small embedded system.

Comment: maybe if it connects on the usb ports of the modem? But modem is also not google cloud ready

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams impossible you said? https://www.amazon.co.uk/LANTRONIX-XPS1002CP-01-S-XPRINTSERVER-CLOUD-PRINT/dp/B00HSMK58A/ref=sr_1_13?ie=UTF8&qid=1509175848&sr=8-13&keywords=cloud+print+server

Comment: If you want to go for a £200 solution instead of a £30 solution, well, don't let me stop you.

Comment: the best way I think is to do that with a google cloud ready printer since it is impossible to do it with a thermal